# Unable to unlink files from CI's asset folder

Tags: codeigniter

I am asking this question over here with the hope that it would be solved by somebody.I have a project in Codeigniter v3.1.3.In the `assets/admin/uploads/photostory_img` directory i have some image files which i am trying to delete using the 'unlink' method.My unlink code in the Controller is like :

```
unlink("assets/admin/uploads/photostory_img/".$ps_old_img);
```

However, i'm getting errors like:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: unlink(assets/admin/uploads/photostory_img/): Permission denied

Filename: nautics/Pstory.php

Line Number: 293

Backtrace:

File: C:\wamp64\www\JSNCI\application\controllers\nautics\Pstory.php
Line: 293
Function: unlink

File: C:\wamp64\www\JSNCI\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

I have searched all over the internet and SO also having similar question , but no success yet.Pleas help me.Its driving me crazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you don't have anything in your $ps_old_image var so you are trying to delete directory with unlink. Check what's inside your variable.

Second problem may be your path. I use unlink in my projects and I delete files with something like:

```
unlink("./assets/admin/uploads/photostory_img/".$ps_old_img);
```

Of course it depends on your certain situation, where do you have your index.php.

Comment: Indeed the '$ps_old_image' variable was empty, causing the unlink method to fail.I should have studied the error message more minutely before posting my problem over here.Looks like i deserve a hard kick in my behind :) . Thanks @cssBlaster21895 for solving my problem.